# JavaScript: Loop after loop not executing

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this JavaScript code, which is being executed after clicking a button.
The for loop is executing fine, but the while loop after that isn't executing at all.
Even the alert is not executing.

```
// FAULTY FUNCTION BEGINNING                   
function swap_table_horizontally_vertically() {


  var old_table = document.getElementById('synopsis_table'),
  old_table_rows = old_table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  cols = old_table_rows.length, rows = old_table_rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length,
  cell, next, temp_row, i = 0, new_table = document.createElement('table');

  // Removes all sort_buttons
  for (i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    var sort_buttons = document.getElementById('sort_buttons');
    sort_buttons.parentNode.removeChild(sort_buttons);
  }

  //NOT EXECUTING FROM HERE
  alert("success");
  while(i < rows) {
    cell = 0;
    temp_row = document.createElement('tr');
    if (i == 0) {
      while(cell < cols) {
        next = old_table_rows[cell++].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

        temp_row.appendChild(next);
      }
      new_table.appendChild(temp_row);
      ++i;
    }
    else {
      while(cell < cols) {
        next = old_table_rows[cell++].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        temp_row.appendChild(next);
      }
      new_table.appendChild(temp_row);
      ++i;
    }
  }


  old_table.parentNode.replaceChild(new_table, old_table);
  new_table.setAttribute("id", "synopsis_table");


}
// FAULTY FUNCTION END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you getting in console?

Comment: The `for` loop condition should have `<` not `<=`. You're trying to process one more element than exists, so getting an exception in the `for` loop. (Also your html is invalid if you have multiple elements all with the same `'sort_buttons'` id.)

Answer (score 0):

Check how many times the first loop is looping. Because I think that the loop starts out good with removing the element by id 'sort_buttons' but because you are using 'id' it will only find one element with that 'id' (you can only have one element with the 'id' sort_buttons').

Thus when looping the second  time it will not find an element with 'id' 'sort_buttons'.

Check in console for any errors.

Tip : Add '`console.log(i);`' in for loop to see how many times the loop is looping.

Answer (score 0):

You iterating i in for loop so after first loop i is higher then rows. You may want to set i = 0 before second loop or use different variable.